# Moving a listview item from one group to another

Tags: winapi, mfc, wtl

I have created a listview in Win32 with group view enabled, I can add Items to a group, but I Have multiple groups and I want an item to pass from group A to group B. I have found the macro ListView_MoveItemToGroup, I call it like so

```
int i =0;
i = m_taskList.GetSelectedIndex();

bool ret = ListView_MoveItemToGroup(m_taskList.m_hWnd,i,LVI_GROUPID_EXEC);
```

but ret is false; What I am doing wrong, the LVI_GROUP_EXEC is added to the litview.

Answer (score 0):

The `LVM_MOVEITEMTOGROUP` message return `TRUE` if successful and `FALSE` otherwise, so either `SendMessage()` is failing, or the message itself is failing or more likely is unrecognized on your version of Windows.  Use `GetLastError()` to differentiate between a message failure and a `SendMessage()` failure.

If you are not seeing the item jump between groups, you will likely have to just remove the item from the ListView first and then re-add it using the desired group.